# CSV Text to columns in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I'm trying to split the elements (a table) of a csv file, where the separator is the pipe line character: `|`

I used the Text to Columns function via excel and it worked, then I recorded the macro and used it but without success.

The data are not aligned in the columns (ex: the date is not in the date column) as if the option "Treat consecutive delimiters as one" is active, but "ConsecutiveDelimiter" in the code is set to False.

This is the code I used:

```
Range("A1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar _
    :="|", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, _
    1), Array(6, 1), Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1), Array(9, 1), Array(10, 1), Array(11, 1), Array(12 _
    , 1), Array(13, 1), Array(14, 1), Array(15, 1), Array(16, 1), Array(17, 1), Array(18, 1), _
    Array(19, 1), Array(20, 1), Array(21, 1), Array(22, 1), Array(23, 1), Array(24, 1), Array( _
    25, 1), Array(26, 1), Array(27, 1), Array(28, 1), Array(29, 1), Array(30, 1), Array(31, 1), _
    Array(32, 1), Array(33, 1), Array(34, 1), Array(35, 1), Array(36, 1), Array(37, 1), Array( _
    38, 1), Array(39, 1), Array(40, 1), Array(41, 1), Array(42, 1), Array(43, 1)), _
    TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```

Thanks in advance

**Edit**

Below a sample of rows:

- the first contains the columns fields
- the second is the output (it shows only a data and then all blank cells)
- the third is the row with all the data (in the csv)
- the fourth shows how the data should be shown (with Excel's text to columns)

XXX code description|HRAFVVH|Ultimate point|Regions|jeis code|verification

Volley

Volley, football||GFV_4589|N/A||05

Volley, football  "blank cell"   GFV_4589   N/A  "blank cell"  05

Comment: @Francesco: you could try reading it as a CSV file using the ADO Text File as in [MSDN - Much ADO About Text Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/ms974559(v=msdn.10))

Comment: I added some example of csv's rows and different output

Comment: I tried your macro and it worked for me so long as there were no empty rows.  I am confused about the comment "the date is not in the date coulumn" since I did not see anything that looked like a date.  Were there any missing rows?  How were the dates represented?

Comment: I wrote "the date is not in the date coulumn" to make an example. Anyway the part of the output that I wrote in the post doesn't work, I only obtain Volley and nothing else

Answer (score -1):

I think that the issue is not the code above but the copy of the data from the csv file. Infact the data are copy and paste in another excel file anche then start the Text to Columns macro.
To copy and paste I use this code:

```
Workbooks(n_o).Worksheets("CSV").Activate
Cells.Select
Selection.Copy
Workbooks(thisworkb).Worksheets("CSV_NEW").Activate
Range("A1").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Workbooks(n_o).Close
```

In fact, after that the macro has pasted the data, also if I did the Text to Columns via excel (manually) the result is not correct.